DynamoDB java sdk v2 client batchWrite retries
Does the DynamoDB Java SDKv2 offer a retry strategy for batchWriteItem calls? I'm looking for a retry strategy that retries items that would otherwise be returned as unprocessedItems.
In the DynamoDB Java SDKv1 there was the DynamoDBMapper default retry strategy to achieve this, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperConfig.DefaultBatchWriteRetryStrategy.html.
I couldn't find anything related to retries out of the box for batch operations in the official javadoc, e.g. https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/DynamoDbClient.html#batchWriteItem(java.util.function.Consumer) or https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/enhanced/dynamodb/package-summary.html.
I was hoping I don't have to implement retries myself on top of the default or enhanced client.

Just ran into this issue a few days ago.
The document suggests a simple loop way now instead of complex retry strategy. And the loop code is simple :)
Document link:

Typically, you would call BatchWriteItem in a loop. Each iteration
would check for unprocessed items and submit a new BatchWriteItem
request with those unprocessed items until all items have been
processed.

And aws also provides code example here

Thank you, looks like this is the recommendation, but in my opinion it also has some drawbacks. I wanted to have exponential backoff, so this already adds some complexity on my side, and code duplication potentially if I need to implement this for more operations.

@yassin looks like we have to do some coding to get exponential backoff working in the Java SDK v2. Seems sometimes DynamoDB isn't very developer-friendly. e.g., I have to deal with the 1MB query limit when trying to get the total count of a table :|
